# How to stop a batch file closing the window

Tags: batch-file

Hi I found another post on here asking this question but the answer didn't work for me. So here is my question.

I have these lines in my file at the moment the pause was supposed to be the answer but it didn't work

```
ping 104.160.141.3
pause
```

what i want it to ping the address, the standard 4 times will be fine but be able to read the output before i close the window.

This is the ip of the lol server so i want to check my ping before i get into game for lag.

Any help please?

Comment: from where are you running your command? if ran from a program without stdin / redirect stdin `pause` won't work.

Comment: I opened a text file  in notepad ++ put those lines in and saved it as .bat. I am then double clicking on it. This is windows 10 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Pause is preventing the batch file from closing the window in my test.

Comment: Open a command prompt, cd to the directory where the script is, and type the name of the script instead.

Comment: But it just keeps running the command over and over? What am i missing her all i want is the exact output i would get if i opened command prompt and put the command ping 104.160.141.3 I am after a way of simply clicking an icon and knowing my ping

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you called your .bat `ping.bat`

Comment: yes it is called ping.bat

Comment: WINKey+R ... `cmd /k ping.exe 104.160.141.3`

Comment: Change your batch file to call `ping.exe ...` instead of just `ping ...` to avoid calling your batch file repeatedly.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: What is the model of your crystal ball? I had a "Merlin 255" one, but it no longer works... **`;)`**

Comment: If i change it to .exe it says app can't run on your pc. sorry was being an idiot this worked fine . Thank you!!!

Comment: @user2801678 It sounds like you renamed the script from `ping.bat` to `ping.exe`, and that is not a valid executable file, hence the error.  You need to change `ping` to `ping.exe` _in the script_, or choose a new name for your `.bat` file entirely.

Comment: @Aacini The 8-bit ones they're the best. A pity they don't build them anymore.

Comment: @user2801678 noone says you're an idiot. This .bat thing happens all the time. The reason why it closed is that you reached the maximum call recursion depth.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just here to conclude all the comments that came together!

As Jean already predicted and it was confirmed your batch-file calls itself immediately after starting and then starts itself and start itself and so on.
After a certain amount of self calls this will be interrupted.

Two ways to solve the problem as well specified in the comments:

1) Change the name of your file to something other than `ping.bat` for example to `pingLol.bat` or something like that. This will prevent the file from calling itself because it does not find itself with the name `ping`.

2) In your script change `ping` to `ping.exe`. This will as well prevent the batch-file to call itself because it is named `ping`**.bat** and not `ping`**.exe**.